# Coloring script output using cat

Tags: terminal, vim, colors, cat, xterm

Is coloring an output possible using cat or similar command?

Let say I have some php or bash script or other. I don't need to edit the file, just to view the source.
So `cat filename` does the job.

But, is it possible to colorize an output making it easier to read, like you can do with `vim` `syntax:on` mode?

Comment: Sorry, put the wrong link for duplicate. [Here is the real dup](http://superuser.com/a/337640/264813). Also see [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/337640/264813)

Comment: That looks like a good reference, but you can't close as a duplicate of a question on another site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, grc will achive what you need.  [github link](https://github.com/pengwynn/grc)

[image]

Comment: Looking good @steve. Does the script colorize the output of the actual scripts as well? (sorry, haven't tested it yet)